# Change shipping cost when buyer buy specific amount price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, web-deployment

I am building an eCommerce website by WordPress and stuck in one place. I want to set a function on my website. When buyer buys $30+ product then I want to make shipping cost zero. So I cannot understand how to do it. Please, someone, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal > 30 ) {
        foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
            $rates[$key]->cost = 0;
        }
    }

    return $rates;

}
```

You can find more examples about shipping fee here:
http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/woocommerce-shipping-fee-changes-condition-met/

Comment: Yes That's worked. Thank you Reigel for your help. :)